# Using Visual studio, can I get the computer name at compile time?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I want to have something like:

```
let COMP_NAME = %some_type_of_flag%
```

So that at compile time, this is changed to

```
let COMP_NAME = "MyComputerName"
```

Edit: I see that my question was incomplete. This is a silverlight application. It appears Environment does not have MachineName. I'm using f#.

Edit: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and the code behind is in f# (Don't ask).  The reason I want to do this is that in our development environment, we run the server on the local machine.  When someone checks out the code, they have to enter their machine name in the code.  Using 'localhost' works when you access the app locally, obviously this won't work when accessing it from another machine.  So the solution must be at build time.

I'm not sure what compiler I'm using, whatever the default f# compiler is in VS2010.

Comment: Furthermore, why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sounds like a case of a prebuild step doing something to an included code file.

Comment: Do you want to access the machine name from your build process (msbuild, etc), or do you want it to be available from within your application code (C#/VB)?

Comment: @SLaks: Not which language, which compiler.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a way to do it simpler than the following. You want to set up a prebuild step (Project -> Properties -> Build Events -> Pre-build event command line).

Here, you can set up a program that will scream through your source files and replace some specific token (`%MachineName%`) with the value of `Environment.MachineName`. This is a program that you will have to write separately.

Answer (score -1):

let COMP_NAME = Environment.MachineName

Comment: That's runtime, which could be a different machine than at build time.

Answer (score -1):

I've found the solution I'm looking for, and it's not getting the computer name at compile time, it's getting the source host at runtime.

```
let host = Application.Current.Host.Source.Host
let uri = new Uri("https://" + host)
```

Comment: This may be a solution to your problem, but it's not an answer to your question. That gives you the machine hosting your (silverlight) app, not the one it was compiled on.